# Can I use Google Analytics Data Import to import notes?

Tags: google-analytics

I use lots of notes in my Google Analytics.  I pretty much note everything that I do.  I wondered if I could import and export notes.

It would be really useful for me to be able to download a CSV or something and then tally it up with social media posts, emails, or other offline activity.

I found this but it was inconclusive. https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3191589?hl=en